# When are module level "constant" arrays being initialized in F#

Tags: f#

The question came up while I was trying to write a lookup table and during debugging I had the impression, that the array might not be initialized at compile or load time, but rather in a lazy way... Unfortunately I could not find the answer in the MSDN chapter about arrays.

Lets look at some sample code first. The code is in a compiled application, not a script, btw.

```
module Foo = 
    let bar = [| for i in 0..9 -> yield (i*i) |]
```

When does `Foo.bar` get initialized?

1. At compile time?
2. At load time?
3. Lazy, when first accessed?
4. Never? (Stays an IEnumerator based sequence despite its array type?)

On a side note, my sequence expression is more complicated than the example above and also uses other functions within scope.

Are there cases which are handled in different ways, such as trivial vs complex eypression or long vs short array etc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Foo.bar` gets initialized at load time - or, when your application starts.

There are slight differences between how this is done for libraries and for applications. For applications, the compiler inserts appropriate initialization into the `Main` method. For libraries, the initialization check is inserted into static constructors of (I believe) all types, so when you access any type from a library, the initialization is done (this may be sometime after `Main`, but still before you run any code from the library).

It does not really depend on what the code is - if it is a value, it will be initialized. There are some values like `Lazy<T>` or `IEnumerable<T>` that do not immediately fully evaluate, but the value is initialized nevertheless.

Comment: The reason I wonder about this is, that if I place a break point into the sequence expression, it is not hit during startup but rather once I access the array. It was a few days ago while I was looking for another problem in my code - I would have to reproduce... but that is what triggered me asking.

Comment: @BitTickler That would certainly be the case if you used `seq { ... }` rather than `[| ... |]` because that creates a lazy `IEnumerable` rather than fully initialized array.